# How to print only elements that are larger than the previous ones in 2D array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, max, nested-loops

John is in a big city and he sees an area of buildings. make a program that will print the number of buildings that are visible by John if he is seeing from the west. The building(s) are only visible if it's not blocked by another buildings that are higher on the same height.

Format Input:

First line, input N which is the size of the area. Afterwards the user will input N x N the heights of the buildings.

Output:

The output will be the number of buildings that are visible.

Sample Input(1):

3

1 2 3

2 1 3

3 1 2

Sample Output(1):

3 | 1 2 3

2 | 2 1 3

1 | 3 1 2

Sample Input(2):

5

8 4 3 2 1

1 1 1 1 1

4 1 3 2 5

2 1 2 5 3

1 1 2 4 2

Sample Output(2):

1 | 8 4 3 2 1

1 | 1 1 1 1 1

2 | 4 1 3 2 5

2 | 2 1 2 5 3

3 | 1 1 2 4 2

This is my current code, it's unfinished

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int building[n][n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &building[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(building[i][j] > max)
            {
                count++;
                max = building[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d |", count);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", building[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do next? or is the whole code wrong?

Comment: If you add some output, what results do you get then?

Comment: By the way, the "2D" part is kind of a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). I recommend you concentrate on one "1D" array at a time. For example by creating a function that takes a single "1D" array, and does the counting and output as specified. Then call this function for each element in the "2D" array.

Comment: Also, it's really useful to hard-code a test case instead of an interactive program.

Comment: Is there another way to do this if I'm not allowed to use function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You changed the requirement after I wrote up the initial solutions to not being able to use functions so here is a revised answer:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

int main(void) {
    // static_assert() it is apparently being removed in c23
    assert(N > 0);
    unsigned building[N][N] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 2, 1, 3 },
        { 3, 1, 2 }
    };
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        unsigned max = *building[i];
        unsigned visible = 1;
        for(unsigned j = 1; j < N; j++) {
            if(building[i][j] > max) {
                max = building[i][j];
                visible++;
            }
        }
        printf("%u |", visible);
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf(" %u", building[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
3 | 1 2 3
2 | 2 1 3
1 | 3 1 2
```

Comment: is it possible do do it without using functions? since I'm not allowed to use it for this problem

Comment: Yeah, just inline the function (copy the function definitions to where they are used and change variable names to avoid conflicts).  It's really dumb that they want you write bad code.

Comment: Heh... the function main() is required.

Comment: Update answer as requested.

Comment: Thank u for ur help, sorry I can't upvote it, I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score -1):

Your presented code has two main problems.

```
int max = 0;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(building[i][j] > max)
        {
            count++;
            max = building[i][j];
        }   
    }
}
```

The first one is that the variable `max` should be set to the value of the first element of a row and `count` should be set at the same time to `1`. Otherwise if the first element of a row is equal to or less than `0` then the variable `count` will not be increased for the first element of the row. And the user can enter negative values because you have an array with the signed element type `int`.

The second problem is that you need to reset the variables `max` and `count` in each iteration of the outer for loop.

And you need to output the calculated value and the current row of the array (as you showed yourself) in each iteration of the outer for loop.

You could write a separate function that calculates the number of visible buildings (elements) of a row of a two-dimensional array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_visible( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    if (n != 0)
    {
        int max = a[0];
        count = 1;

        for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (max < a[i])
            {
                ++count;
                max = a[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        int building[n][n];
    
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                scanf( "%d", &building[i][j] );
            }
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf( "%zu |", count_visible( building[i], n ) );
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                printf( " %d", building[i][j] );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }
}
```

If to enter numbers shown in your second test case then the result program output will look like

```
1 | 8 4 3 2 1
1 | 1 1 1 1 1
2 | 4 1 3 2 5
2 | 2 1 2 5 3
3 | 1 1 2 4 2
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without function? since I'm not allowed to use it